# Bootloader - programação

Tags: c

Tenho visto esse código que de um bootloader :

https://ghostbin.com/paste/mwpub

E não consigo entender essa parte :

```
MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN    equ 1<<0    
MBOOT_MEM_INFO      equ 1<<1
```

Bom eu queria saber o que significa esse  `equ1<<0` , `equ 1<<1`

Answer (score 0):

A palavra `equ` serve para definir constantes, já `<<` é um operador que "desloca" os bits um número para a esquerda, esse tipo de operador normalmente é utilizado para definir flags.

Veja mais em:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489h/Caccddic.html